# "dyld`__abort_with_payload" error and exit code 45 on attempted reverse engineering of iOS app

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, jailbreak, lldb

I am attempting to reverse engineer an iOS app to remove jailbreak detection. When using lldb, I got this output:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xe26e, 0x00000001012322f8 dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
```

I looked it up and `__abort_with_payload` has to do with embedded binaries or code signing or something, which gives me reason to believe it has something to do with how mobilesubstrate injects dylibs into apps.

I tried disabling mobilesubstrate, and running lldb again. This time, it gave a different issue:

```
Process 16662 resuming
Process 16662 exited with status = 45 (0x0000002d)
```

What is exit code 45? Google searching didn't help very much, but according to [osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com), it can mean `ENOTSUP` or "Operation not supported". What does "Operation not supported" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `PT_DENY_ATTACH`.

Many SO answers already cover it to some extent to give you an idea: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034321/implementing-the-pt-deny-attach-anti-piracy-code) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213240/disabling-debug-sessions-on-ios-is-that-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1) . Even in more details covered in Alexander O'mara 's blog post [here](https://alexomara.com/blog/defeating-anti-debug-techniques-macos-ptrace-variants/)

To **counter it** in lldb before your executable runs type:

```
b ptrace
```

You should see something like this:

```
Breakpoint 5: where = libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ptrace, address = 0x00000001c2b17140
```

Giving you indication where it's actually handled.

When you **hit the ptrace breakpoint** type:

```
th r
```

i.e. shortened syntax for `thread return`

It will force exiting the ptrace function without actually doing the denying part.

After the `th r` you may see something like this

```
->  0x100daa548 <+140>: str    w0, [sp, #392]
    0x100daa54c <+144>: bl     0x100b01cb8               ; ___lldb_unnamed_function1756$$prodx
    0x100daa550 <+148>: bl     0x100b02538               ; ___lldb_unnamed_function1760$$prodx
    0x100daa554 <+152>: bl     0x100daa470               ; ___lldb_unnamed_function29542$$prodx
```

The code snippet is from OP and is irrelevant. What is important is `ip`(i.e. instruction pointer register) is pointing to the **next** assembly instruction after the `ptrace` call. Hence to see what's going on we must disassemble preceding assembly code. Every single arm64 assembly instruction is 4 bytes hence we type:

```
di -s 0x100daa544
```

That will most likely yield:

```
0x100daa544    bl     <some address> ; aka ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH, ...)
```

So now you can just inspect the actual bytes of the opcodes^:

```
x 0x100daa544 -c 4
```

These are the bytes to replace with the nop mentioned below.

However it *may happen* the ptrace is made directly **instead** through a syscall like this (that's what libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ptrace: actually does internally) :

```
mov x0, #0x1f ; this is PT_DENY_ATTACH 31 syscall argument
mov x16, #0x1a ; x0,x16 can be set in numerous ways so I skip the opcodes
01 10 00 D4    svc  #0x80
```

This is AARCH64 (aka arm64) assembly so I'm assuming your device is iPhone5s or newer. To further obfuscate it, the instructions might be separated by some nonrelevant instructions. If you need to follow this path check the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985859/ios-arm64-syscalls/).

So replacing `01 10 00 D4` in your favourite hex editor with

```
1f 20 03 d5      nop
```

should get you going.

One could go crazy with not using `0x80` in `svc` for the syscall

```
01 00 00 d4  svc #0
21 00 00 d4  svc #1
01 02 00 d4  svc #0x10
e1 1f 00 d4  svc #0xff
```

Each of them would happen to work, but it might break at any point (still it hasn’t since iOS7 up to present iOS 13).

**Final remarks:**

If you actually modify the binary some extra protection mechanism might exist like checksum and other self integrity checks. That's definitely beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it's really helpful. I want to just nop out the ptrace section. I'm not very good with asm, but I don't see anything like what you showed. Could you point me in the right direction as to what to search for? Here's a log of lldb: https://paste.bingner.com/paste/ve4as

Comment: Yes it does indeed. Thanks for all the help.